# I'm willing to use CO2 tablets in my planted aquarium but I'm worried that it may cause any harm to my guppy fish

Tags: aquarium

If there is anyone who knows about planted aquarium please help me.
Is [ISTA CO2 tablets](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B010HR46CI/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_xRTqEb56H7DWT) good for planted aquarium?

Will this harm my fishes?

Should I use both CO2 and oxygen filter in my tank?

Comment: I would say it's a waste of money. The CO2 would degass almost immediately and wouldn't be available to the plants. If you aren't looking to get a CO2 injection system, I would go for Flourish Excel or a similar liquid product that you dose daily. It's extremely well tested and definitely safe for your fish.

Comment: @Jestep consider writing an answer?